# mount --bind other user as myself

Tags: mount, bind-mount

I'm using fstab to bind a folder that belongs to another user in one of my own directories. I know that I can map users when I mount an SSHFS, I've been doing some research and I can't find a `mount --bind` equivalent.

Is there any way I can mount another user's folder and files as my own?

Update: It doesn't necessarily *have* to be `mount --bind`. It just has to do something similar while mapping users, and can be done on startup.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can't do that with the Linux bind mount kernel feature. But you can do it with the [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) filesystem [bindfs](http://bindfs.org/). Bindfs is slower than bind mounts and doesn't pass extended attributes, but on the flip side, it can be used by non-root users and on Unix variants other than Linux, and most importantly for you, allows simple transformations of ownership and permissions.

Assuming that your user name is `andy` and the other user is `bob`:

```
bindfs -u andy /home/bob/stuff /home/andy/bobs-stuff
```

In `/etc/fstab`, that would translate to:

```
bindfs#/home/bob/stuff /home/andy/bobs-stuff fuse force-user=andy 0 0
```